# Can i create a drill down on category in Fusion-chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fusioncharts

I am working with Fusion-chart library,

I have a situation where I want to scroll page on click of (any bar / Area ) of category to specific div.

It means I have 7 multi series categories (5 bars in each category) in a graph and 7 separate graphs for each category, I want to scroll page to specific category graph on click of that category area/bar.

**How can I achieve it?**

**Can I handle it in following node?**

```
"categories": [
    {
        "category": [
            {"label": "G Outlooks","link": "JavaScript:funname('go')"},
            {"label": "Instruments","link": "JavaScript:funname('mi')"},
            {"label": "G Services","link": "JavaScript:funname('gs')"},
            {"label": "S Services","link": "JavaScript:funname('ss')"},
            {"label": "P Programs","link": "JavaScript:funname('pp')"},
            {"label": "Resources Availability","link": "JavaScript:funname('rac')"},
            {"label": "Resources Functionality","link": "JavaScript:funname('raf')"}
        ]
    }
],
"dataset": [
    {
        "seriesname": "first",
        "data": [{"value":168},{"value":134},{"value":119},{"value":64},{"value":82},{"value":32},{"value":18}]
    },
    {
        "seriesname": "second",
        "data": [{"value":38},{"value":39},{"value":38},{"value":31},{"value":53},{"value":73},{"value":55}]
    },
    {
        "seriesname": "third",
        "data": [{"value":19},{"value":38},{"value":50},{"value":67},{"value":62},{"value":109},{"value":79}]
    },
    {
        "seriesname": "fourth",
        "data": [{"value":5},{"value":13},{"value":23},{"value":33},{"value":20},{"value":84},{"value":94}]
    },
    {
        "seriesname": "fifth",
        "data": [{"value":4},{"value":10},{"value":4},{"value":39},{"value":17},{"value":39},{"value":75}]
    }
]
```

**Update:**

i used ***link*** attribute in category object but it adds link on category name only.

Comment: no you can't make a drill-down directly in category as fusion chart does not allows it. you have to make a drill-down on a series or data of a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you alot!

I have created link for each data entry as Javascript call, and then use something to scroll the page to your lower content! You can use

```
window.scrollTo()
```

or if you use jQuery then you can animate it with `animate` method

```js
function goto(link){
  window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector('.' + link ).offsetTop );
}

FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var topStores = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'bar2d',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '400',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Top 5 Stores by Sales",
                "subCaption": "Last month",
                "yAxisName": "Sales (In USD)",
                "numberPrefix": "$",
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
                "placeValuesInside": "1",
                "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
                "showAxisLines": "1",
                "axisLineAlpha": "25",
                "divLineAlpha": "10",
                "alignCaptionWithCanvas": "0",
                "showAlternateVGridColor": "0",
                "captionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
                "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                "toolTipPadding": "5"
            },
            
            "data": [
                {
                    "label": "Bakersfield Central",
                    "link": "JavaScript:goto('p1')",
                    "value": "880000"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "Garden Groove harbour",
                    "link": "JavaScript:goto('p2')",
                    "value": "730000"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "Los Angeles Topanga",
                    "link": "JavaScript:goto('p3')",
                    "value": "590000"
                }, 
            ],
        }
    }).render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>

<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>

<p class="p0">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it <b>1</b>?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</p>

<p class="p1">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it <b>1</b>?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</p>

<p class="p2">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it <b>2</b>?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).



</p>
<p class="p3">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it <b>3</b>?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).



</p>
```

Comment: It is not working in my case, Reason is i have multi series graph where each category has 5 bars in it.

Comment: i updated and mentioned category code, wait a bit let me one series aswell. Thanks for all your hard efforts, You got alot of respect in my heart.

Comment: I have updated my question and added datasource aswell. Thanks again.